# Automatically extract and add data attributes from classes

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am using an app that outputs HTML and it only supports adding custom classes.

So given,

```
<div class="my-button data-featherlight-hash-mylightbox data-jarallax data-speed-num-zero-point-two">Content</div>
```

how can I change it to

```
<div class="my-button" data-featherlight="#mylightbox" data-jarallax data-speed="0.2">Content</div>
```

using jQuery?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attr to add HTML tag attributes by jQuery.

```
<div class="my-button">Content</div>

$('.my-button').attr('data-featherlight', '#mylightbox');
$('.my-button').attr('data-jarallax data-speed', '0.2');
```

Comment: Indeed. The requirement though is to have them automatically be added for the various HTML tags based on the class names in the format I've specified.

Also, it should also be versatile w.r.t numbers. Ex.: `data-speed-num-five-point-nine` class should be removed and `data-speed="5.9"` added to the tag.

`data-speed-num-nine` -> `data-speed="9"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one ;)

```
var getElem     = jQuery('.my-button');
var getClasses  = getElem.attr("class").split(' ');
jQuery( getClasses ).each( function( index, value ){
    if( value.indexOf( 'data-featherlight' ) != -1 ){
        getElem.attr( 'data-featherlight', value.replace( 'data-featherlight', '' ) );
    }
} );
```

That's for featherlight only but you'll easily add the other ones. I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to Jeffrey, here's the final script:

    var getElem = jQuery('.my-button');
var getClasses = getElem.attr("class").split(' ');
jQuery(getClasses).each(function (index, value) {
    if (value.indexOf('data-') != -1) {
        var d = value.substring(0, value.indexOf("_"));
        var newval = value.replace(d, '');
        newval = newval.replace('hash-', '#');
        newval = newval.replace('_', '');
        if (d.length > 1) {
            getElem.attr(d, newval.replace('__', '.'));
            getElem.removeClass(value);
        }
    }
});

Comment: Given these sample classes in the markup:

data-speed_0__2

data-featherlight_hashmylightbox

data-jarallax_